# Reference for theorems in Hirsch

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology, manifolds-with-boundary

In Hirsch's differential topology, we find the following theorems on page 31:

4.1 Theorem: Let $M$ be a $C^r$ $\partial$-manifold and $N$ a $C^r$ manifold, $r \geq 1$. Let $f : M \to N$ be a $C^r$ map. If $y \in N - \partial N$ a regular value for both $f$ and $f|_{\partial M}$, then $f^{-1}(y)$ is a neat $C^r$ submanifold of $M$.

4.2 Theorem: Let $A \subset N$ be a $C^r$ submanifold and $f : M \to N$ a $C^r$ map. Suppose $\partial A = \emptyset$ and $f$, $f|_{\partial M}$ are both transverse to $A$. Then $f^{-1}(A)$ is a $C^r$ submanifold with boundary $f^{-1}(A) \cap \partial M$.

The proofs of these results are left as exercise. I know how to prove them for boundaryless manifolds using the constant rank theorem, but I'm not sure at all how to adapt this for boundary manifolds. Any hints or references would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's the same thing - there's a version of the constant rank theorem for manifolds with boundary. If you don't know it, you should try to prove it - it's essentially the same.

Comment: @MikeMiller: could you provide the statement of such theorem? I'm curious as to how the $f|_{\partial M} \pitchfork A$ condition is going to matter.

Comment: See Lemma 18 [here](https://www.math.columbia.edu/~mlipyan/SingHom.pdf). This is even more general, about manifolds with corners. Even if you're not interested in this level of generality you'll see the idea.